# How to perform integration with Dirac Delta in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to calculate the integral

$$
y(x)=\int^b_a dz\delta(x-w_z)
$$

were $\delta$ is the dirac delta function, $a=-3$, $b=3$ and $w$ is a one-dimensional matrix such that for some values of $z$ there is an associated value of $w$.

I think this Integral is related to the [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure#Definition).

Comment: Maybe `Integrate[DiracDelta[x - w z], {z, -3, 3}]` modifying an example from the docs for `DiracDelta`.

Comment: It's your integral. You tell us.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I have preformed your integral and got an error "Part specification z is neither an integer nor a list of  integers."

Comment: That's not what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPpjK.png

Comment: @MichaelE2, but you just multiplied $w$ by $z$. $w$ is a one dimensional matrix and for some values of $z$ there is a associated value in $w$. So basically $w$ is like a function of $z$.

Comment: @MichaelE2, So $w$ is like two dimensional matrix where one column is the values of $z$ and the other column is the associated value of $w$.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I not sure why you multiplied $w$ by $z$.

Comment: @gbd: if you treat the Dirac delta function as  an atom measure, then the problems with the ODES of  such type $y''(x)+y(x)=\delta(x-1)$ raise.

Comment: @gbd: Also `Integrate[DiracDelta[z - 3], {z, -3, 3}]` produces `HeavisideTheta[0]` i.e. undefined. BTW, I have never seen integrals of such type in serious math literature.

Comment: @user64496, I think you forgot to add $w$ to the integral

Comment: @gbd: I presented a simpler example. Think of $w=1$. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: `w z` is a one-dimensional matrix (1x1) that is a function of `z` with a parameter `w` (change `w` to `y` if it’s confusing). You don’t give us a real example that can be computed, so I had to make one up. — @MrDi Why not? There was no info about $w(z)$, now $w_z$. Obviously the integral with a generic `w[z]` wouldn’t evaluate.

Comment: @MichaelE2: How to define the difference $x-w_z$ between a real number $x$ and a one-dimensional matrix $w_z$? Lets us put a function of $z$ with a parameter $w$ to be equal to $3$ for each $z$ and $w$.

Comment: @user64494 `DiracDelta` is a tool to be used when it makes sense to use it. `Integrate[DiracDelta[z - 3], {z, -3, 3}]` is not a sensible application. Telling a carpenter to avoid using a hammer because you can't drive screws with it is not good advice.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Can you ground your claim "`Integrate[DiracDelta[z - 3], {z, -3, 3}]` is not a sensible application"? I see such an example in the Integration section of the documentation to `DiracDelta`: `Integrate[DiracDelta[x-a], {x,0,y},Assumptions ->a\[Element]\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]&&y>0]`, where `y==a` for positive `a` is allowed.

Comment: Rule of thumb (coming from the underlying mathematics): If different function approximations to the Dirac delta functional give different integral results, then that integral is not well defined. This applies to the 1D case where the singular point of the integrand coincides with an endpoint of integration.

Comment: @user64494 Your homework is to construct an analog computer to compute `Integrate[DiracDelta[z - a], {z, -3, 3}]`, and report on the answers it yields for different values of `a`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The rule comes not only from the underlying mathematics, but from the applications where the abstract mathematical object `DiracDelta` is used to represent some physical phenomenon.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Concerning rule of thumb: both `Integrate[UnitBox[(z - 3)/eps]/eps, {z, -3, 3}, 
 Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]` and `Integrate[eps/((z-3)^2+eps^2)/Pi,{z,-3,3},Assumptions->eps>0&&eps<1]` produce expressions tending to `1/2` if `eps` approaches zero from above.

Comment: @JohnDoty:  I don't understand your remark. I am PhD in math for ages. Regard.

Comment: @user64494 That you don't understand it indicates a hole in your mathematics education. We all have those. I suggest you read Bracewell's "The Fourier Transform And Its Applications" if you wish to learn.

Comment: @user64494 Try approximations that are slightly off-center. Say `In[32]:= Integrate[UnitBox[(z - 3 - eps^2/2)/eps]/eps, {z, -3, 3}, 
 Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1]

Out[32]= 3/8` Yet this is a perfectly fine approximation (as `eps->0` from above) to a delta function centered at 3.

Comment: @DanielLichblau: You are right.That object `Integrate[DiracDelta[z - 3], {z, -3, 3}]` makes no sense.

Comment: @JohnDoty: How is your second remark related to the question under consideration? Can you give a concrete comment? Deep regard again.

Comment: @user64494 Well, if you'd do the experiment with the analog computer, you'd learn how the Dirac delta function works in reality. Remember, Dirac invented it to represent the behavior of physical systems, not as pure mathematics. If your mathematics can't handle it, that means your mathematics struggles with representing reality. Such math can be fascinating, but it's not something I'd use in my work as as scientific instrument designer. On the other hand, `DiracDelta` is profoundly useful.

Comment: @JohnDoty: As it is written in [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) , " On the other hand, the concept of a generalized function reflects the fact that in reality a physical quantity cannot be measured at a point; only its mean values over sufficiently small neighbourhoods of a given point can be measured. Thus, the technique of generalized functions serves as a convenient and adequate apparatus for describing the distributions of various physical quantities". Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 Indeed. The basic concepts of geometry are rather treacherous in the real world. As Reuben Hersh pointed out, circles do not exist in reality. Geometry studies the necessary properties of things like circles even though they only exist in the imagination. They happen to be useful as approximate representations of real things, as one may with suitable care successfully associate their properties with those of real things. With similar care, delta functions are no more treacherous than circles here.